# Collapse information according to certain column of a line

Tags: python, line

For the matrix as below

```
    A  20  200
    A  10  150
    B  60  200
    B  80  300
    C  90  400
    C  30  300
```

My purpose is trying to: for each category (labelled as A,B,C..in the 1st column), I'd like to find the minimum as well as maximum numbers (as biggest range). So expect to see:

```
A  10  200
B  60  300
C  30  400
```

So how could I do using Python?

Comment: Generally min/max algorithms work like this. You assign the max to the first value, then run a for loop that compares each value to the max, and , if it exceeds it, sets the max to that value.   If you can use `numpy`, there will be functions `np.max` `np.min` to do that for you. You may also need to use `transpose` on your data to get them into the right order. So why don't you provide the data in the shape that you have them as a Python variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by:

```
maxs, mins = {}, {}
for line in fd:
    category, small, big = line.split()
    if category not in maxs or big > maxs[category]:
        maxs[category] = big
    if category not in mins or small < mins[category]:
        mins[category] = small

# final printings
for category in maxs:
    print(category, mins[category], maxs[category], sep='\t')
```

This returns dicts, that can be merged using `{c: (mins[c], maxs[c]) for c in maxs}`.

This code assume that an iterable of lines is named `fd`. Could be an opened file containing the matrix in raw text.

If the order is important, a good solution is to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of the regular dict for `mins` and `maxs`.